# I run about 100 small traffic websites, what host would you recommend (expansion is planned)?

Tags: php, html, hosting, lamp

I know there are plenty of suggestions like asmallorange, linode, etc, but how well do these apply to someone who is running 100 sites?
Traffic can be anywhere from zero hits a month up to about 1,000.
The host I'm using right now doesn't allow access to httpd.conf or other important apache features.
If I had to guess, it seems like Linode or other services like it are right up my alley, however, I am not great with linux. I can get by alright in Ubuntu, but that's about it. Will this knowledge be enough to get by with Linode?

What about domain name transfers? The way it works now for me is if someone has an existing site, I ask them to get the domain transfer code and then I send the domain name xfer code to my current host and they take care of the rest. Does Linode take care of domain name transfers? How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest Amazon AWS. Especially with the new "free tier" offering, you can run a surprisingly powerful group of systems at low cost and you have complete control over all aspects of your setup.

As for DNS, all you need to do is change your DNS records to point to your new servers - or did you want to change your DNS provider too?

Answer (score 0):

For that many websites, I would go for either a virtual or dedicated server.

Costs as low as 30$ a month, and you can customize it as much as you want.
Add cross site analytics (like Piwik), etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a linode (don't know about asmallorange). It starts at $20/month and for 1000 hits a month would be more than sufficient. With Linode you would get bandwidth bundled which in case of EC2 would be extra.

If you want to move the website why do you want to do domain transfer? Just ask them to point to your new IP instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a VPS from various providers, which allows you to fine tune your memory usage and also choose the web delivery application. Apache, LigHTTPD or NginX

If you go with a shared hosting account your forced to use the settings that the hosting company use.

A dedicated server might be overkill depending on the costs you wish to spend.